# how to close a NSWindowController without close button by using a custom shortcut without Xcode

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a NSWindowController which closes itself by pressing the 'x' key and works great

[image]

as you see, very clear my Window, this is the code

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    //If the key is X just closes the window
    if ([theEvent.characters.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
        [self.window performClose:self];
    }
}
```

but when I remove the TitleBar or the close control it just stops working...

[image]

I want it this way because its required to have my windows without buttons, just to close or do task by shortcuts and commands, in this case the X button to close, how to perform this in a NSWindowController without the close control or titlebar

thanks for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    //If the key is X just closes the window
    if ([theEvent.characters.uppercaseString isEqualToString:@"X"]) {
        [self close];
    }
}
```